# Azure release pipeline for static web app

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a React app and I've set up a build pipeline that publishes the `build` directory as artifacts.

[image]

I was anticipating setting up a release pipeline to deploy it like I would with AzureFunctions or an AppService.

But apparently not: when I created the static website it has created a new build pipeline which also deploys. Why would you want every build to deploy? This is nonsense.

Also, the branch name is hard-coded somehow and can't be changed. Obviously I'll want to change that to `master` after I've got it working.

[image]

Furthermore, when trying to create a release pipeline there is no task for Azure static website.

What is going on?

Can I have a normal build and release like everything else?
Why does this have to be different -- the inconsistency is confusing and infuriating.

Comment: I'm just now discovering the same thing - it's frustrating that the processes aren't consistent.  It's particularly problematic when the static web app is the "frontend" that needs to be deployed separately but concurrently to match a "backend".

Answer (score 0):

> But apparently not: when I created the static website it has created a
> new build pipeline which also deploys. Why would you want every build
> to deploy? This is nonsense.

You can change the trigger of the pipeline to make the deployment be done as you want.

Check these official documents:

[CI Trigger for DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers)

[PR Trigger for DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers)

If you don't want the pipeline trigger automatically, you can replace the trigger part of the pipeline as this:

`trigger: none`

> Also, the branch name is hard-coded somehow and can't be changed.
> Obviously I'll want to change that to master after I've got it
> working.

Just like the above, the design of Azure SWA in this regard is a bit counter-intuitive, these settings are also not operated on the Azure Portal side, but on the DevOps side.

You need follow these to change the source:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

After the above two steps, the source of the Azure SWA will be changed successfully, but the UI of the Azure Portal side will not change immediately at this time. A success deployment will change it:

[image]

Comment: And it has to do a new build? It is impossible to deploy to an SWA the artefacts from a build?

Comment: Yes, building and deploying a SWA is simple and straightforward, but the problem is it cannot be performed separately from the build process.  This is an issue when it needs to be deployed concurrently when another artifact (such as a backend app).